# Why is <li> padding being interpreted different on Mac? 

Tags: css, padding, html-lists

I have a wrapper, then ul, then li with padding and left float.

In Mac Firefox and Safari, the last `<li>` child moves to the next line.

I’m using margin auto and a reset. It renders fine on PC in every browser (not IE9, but I have conditional style sheet for this not included).

- http://www.rv333.com/stackoverflow/index.html
- http://www.rv333.com/stackoverflow/pc.png/http://www.rv333.com/stackoverflow/pc.png

Here’s the code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;

}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 960px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color: #e7e2d7;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    margin: 0;
}
li.selected {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #218308;
    background-image: url(../ui/nav-selected-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}
li a {
    color: #4a4a4a; 
}
li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
li.selected a {
    color: #fff;    
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a>Becket Court</a></li>
        <li><a>Darwin College</a></li>
        <li><a>Eliot College</a></li>
        <li><a>Keynes College</a></li>
        <li><a>Park Wood</a></li>
        <li><a>Rutherford College</a></li>
        <li><a>Tyler Court</a></li>
        <li><a>Woolf College</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a reason the padding is interpreted differently on Mac? Or am I just making a stupid mistake?

Comment: please edit your question to show some screenshots of what `<li>` padding looks like on Firefox and Safari on the Macintosh, versus what you see on Windows or other architectures.

Comment: also, some code samples would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d guess that the padding is actually exactly the same on Mac and PC, but the font is rendered slightly differently, resulting in the width of some `<li>`s being greater on the Mac, resulting in the last item wrapping onto the next line.

You can check using the Firebug add-on for Firefox on both Mac and PC, or Google Chrome’s built-in inspector.

Comment: how should I render the font as em instead of px for more accuracy?

Comment: @gilesadamthomas: if the font rendering is being affected by the operating system, I don’t think changing the font unit in the CSS will affect it (although you’re welcome to try). You’re better off increasing your wrapper’s width, or reducing the amount of padding, so that you’ve got a couple of spare pixels to account for text differences.

Comment: @gilesadamthomas: you’re very welcome, glad to help. If you like, you can vote up (click the up arrow) and/or accept (click the check mark) my answer, cos then I get reputation points.

Comment: not enough reputation to vote up im afraid but ill come back and vote up when I do..

Comment: @gilesadamthomas: ah yes of course, I always forget that. I think accepting the answer gets you reputation points too, so you might try that.